# How do I install network drivers on my Ubuntu Server OS via command line

Tags: 13.04, drivers, server, ethernet, nic

Basically as the title says, I haven't any idea how I am to install network drivers onto my Dell Poweredge 2950 II. I am a complete noob when it comes to command line and its operations.

Just to add-to this, considering that drivers may not be the issue, I plug in the ethernet cable in both of the ports in the back. A red light blinks when there is no internet connection. When plugging in the cable it continues to blink, but the cable responds with the nic with a solid green light on the left and a yellowish/orange blinking on the right.

Using 13.04

If I leave out any required information please tell me.

EDIT: Ethernet = https://i.stack.imgur.com/q41uY.jpg

Results of sudo ifconfig = https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAYD9.png

Comment: For most Ethernet ports the opensource drivers are built right into the Linux kernel of Ubuntu. You don't have to install anything. It should work out of the box. This may be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, any linux has drivers out of the box. I never had experience looking for network card (NIC) drivers elsewhere.

Using the terminal try this and post the outcome here:

$sudo ifconfig

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CroQrOI.png

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your Ethernet card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: I added them to question.